# Google datastudio change report filter dynamically

Tags: looker-studio

I have data from many clients collected via my Google Analytics and clients would like to access their reports. At this point, I clone a report, change a report filter, and give them access. But now I end up having a lot of similar reports where the only difference is the client name in the filter.

I would to create one report template and simply pass programmatically the filter value equal to the client name. Is it something possible to do in Google Data Studio?

Added clarification:
We use a custom content group called Business to record what client the data belong to and then we filter Content Group(Business) = Client_name

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the data is set up (if required you could perhaps use a blended Google Sheet to link the contact details), one way could be to have a look through the recently introduced [Filter by email address](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9713766), thus if each row of data has a clients email address, then it will automatically filter based on the respective client.

Adding a link to a blog post by Mehdi Oudjida to elaborate: [Google Data Studio – Filter by email address overview & creative usage for report personalization](https://www.wissi.fr/blog/analytics/20200214/google-data-studio-filter-by-email-address-introduction-and-use-for-personalization/)

Comment: We created a custom content group Business where we store the client name. Then my report uses filter on Content Group(Business) = <client name> to filter to the correct data.

Comment: Would it be possible to add an email address that's linked to the Business field in the Content Group? Haven't tried this out, but if an email field is present (one that's linked to the client name), then it should be possible to filter by email address at the Data Source thus filtering by client, while sending out the Reports.

Comment: Added a blog post that demonstrates a way of going about the process. Quoting the specific section: "Create a calculated field 'email address' converting hostnames or websites names to the right email addresses of Google account users, inside Google Analytics data source".

Comment: There is no way to add parametre to Google Analytics data? Some data sources allow it, but could not find for GA. Email would not work as our site is fully anonymous, we don't even have any registration functionality.